# Not getting pending transactions with web3py

Tags: python, web3py

I am writing some code to read the pending transactions on the blockchain (BSC). Following the docs and other answers in here, I developed this solution:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("wss://*.bsc.quiknode.pro/*/"))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

event_filter = w3.eth.filter('pending')

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    for entry in event_filter.get_new_entries():
        print(entry)
```

However, I am not getting any entry from this code. If I run a different filter `w3.eth.filter('latest')` I seem to get the latest blocks.

How can I obtain all pending transaction hashes? Should I get them from the latest block?